# Swing based application architecture

Tags: java, swing

I am planning to develop a swing application for developing a large in-house software. 
Features:
  It should be menu based.
  Modular
  Secure

Can you please help in choosing the right architecture and technologies to use with Swing. Also any good sample should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do have a look at the NetBeans platform. It makes things a log easier. Especially for "large" applications, the module concept will help you a lot (e.g. for structuring your application)

It has a learning curve, but I think in the long run it will help you.

This article might give you an idea:

http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-belgian-radio-monitoring-toolkit?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fnetbeans+%28NetBeans+Zone%29

Comment: Thanks. How about eclipse RCP or Spring RCP ?

Comment: @MountainRock: Eclipse is not Swing (which you explicitely mentioned). I don't know Spring RCP

Answer (score 1):

The limited requirements you list don't really eliminate any framework options.  Get a little further in your requirements and design before you determine what you need to add to Swing.

Answer (score 1):

To strengthen eugener's claims, I would recommend looking into Spring Rich Client, or its successor Valkyrie RCP.

Comment: Thanks will look at Spring RCP http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html
   Also any suggestions on eclipse RCP ? : http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **multi-tier architecture based on Spring Framework**. We had a very good experience using Spring on the client as well as in our own application server. It makes difficult tasks a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid to start with a framework that is still under development (although many of its parts are now stable), you couls take a look at [GUTS](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home).

It also requires knowledge of Guice Dependency Injection library, which helps having a very clean design of the whole application.